# usage of the word of

Tags: prepositions

I wonder if the usage of ''of'' in this sentence is correct? The sentence is 
'' As continuation of completion of the common market''.
Can the usage of ''of'' two or three times be possible?

Comment: Why should it not be possible? (I'm not sure what "continuation of completion" really means, but it's probably that concept which needs to be better defined, than the use of multiple *ofs*.)

Comment: I agree with @Andrew.  I don't know what *"continuation of completion"* is supposed to mean ... once you've completed something, how can you continue to complete it?

Answer (score 1):

Question: I wonder if the usage of "of" in this sentence is correct?

The sentence is: "As continuation of completion of the common market"

This isn't a sentence, because it's not complete. And, "of" can occur as many times as may be required.

Assuming that it's only a part of a larger sentence, I would rephrase it as follows:

"As the work towards the completion of the common market continues... "

Comment: My pleasure! All the best!